# XML xs:int hexadecimal value

Tags: xml, xsd, hex

I want to store a number in an XML file with type of  or another simple integer type, but allow the user to enter the number in a hexadecimal format. Does the XML standard allow for this as I can't find anything relevant?

For example, if the XSD says:

```
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
```

then I want the XML to be able to say:

```
<value>0xFF00FF</value>
```

or whatever the notation for hexadecimal would be.

Obviously I can try it but that only proves support in one particular implementation, not whether it's a standard. I don't particularly care whether saving to XML loses the base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. `xs:integer` is a derived/subset type of `xs:decimal`, which representation is [defined as](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal)

> decimal has a lexical representation consisting of a finite-length sequence of decimal digits (#x30-#x39) separated by a period as a decimal indicator. An optional leading sign is allowed. If the sign is omitted, "+" is assumed. Leading and trailing zeroes are optional. If the fractional part is zero, the period and following zero(es) can be omitted. For example: -1.23, 12678967.543233, +100000.00, 210.

You could remove the 0x and set it to hexBinary, although you lose the number semantic.

Answer (score 6):

I’d use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in a `<xs:pattern>` element.

```
<xs:element name="value" use="required">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+|[0-9]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

This allows you to store both decimal and hexadecimal number (with mandatory `0x` prefix). However, you’ll need to handle it specifically while converting the string to a number.

Answer (score 4):

I needed this myself and wound up here.

Here is a 32 bit unsigned integer type that will allow you to enter the value as either hex or decimal.

```
<xs:simpleType name="U32BitHexInt">
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:unsignedInt">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:pattern value="0x[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2):

XSD doesn't allow this.

But XSD 1.1 does allow implementation-defined facets, including pre-lexical facets, and Saxon exploits this freedom to provide the saxon:preprocess facet described here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!schema-processing/extensions11/preprocess

This would allow you to accept hexadecimal notation as a lexical representation of an integer type. Only drawback (probably a big one!) is that it will only work with Saxon.